TensorFlow not detecting GPU even though CUDA toolkit is installed
Total noob here but I'm running Fedora 39(with GNOME).
I want to setup TensorFlow to use my RTX 3050 mobile.
I'm getting the following message upon running the command tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices():
2024-04-19 12:22:40.813797: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-04-19 12:22:40.814316: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-04-19 12:22:40.826633: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-04-19 12:22:40.930638: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-19 12:22:43.237784: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-04-19 12:22:47.013753: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-04-19 12:22:47.015129: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]

I already have all the prerequisites installed as given here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux_1
NVIDIA Drivers
❯ nvidia-smi --version
NVIDIA-SMI version  : 550.67
NVML version        : 550.67
DRIVER version      : 550.67
CUDA Version        : 12.4

CUDA Toolkit
❯ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Mar_28_02:18:24_PDT_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.4, V12.4.131
Build cuda_12.4.r12.4/compiler.34097967_0

LibCUDNN
I don't exactly know how to verify this but I installed it following the commands here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=RHEL&target_version=9&target_type=rpm_local
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/9.1.0/local_installers/cudnn-local-repo-rhel9-9.1.0-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i cudnn-local-repo-rhel9-9.1.0-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf clean all
sudo dnf -y install cudnn-cuda-12

I also installed nvidia-pyindex and nvidia-cudnn using pip.
I have already added all the relevant paths to my ~/.zshrc file by :
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.4/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.4/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

Could someone help me out with this? Its been rather frustrating.

According to this table the tested/working version for TF 2.16 is CUDA 12.3 and CuDNN 8.9. Try these versions, as TF seems to no even recognize your CUDA installation.

How can I check my CUDNN version?

I'm sure you can google that. In your question it seems you installed 9.1.0.
